# How to change the label according to the item name of a listwidget in qt 5.3.1?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt-designer, qlistwidget

I'm trying to make a sound application that takes multiple sounds and plays them. sound names or paths should be in the listwidget. whatever I choose sounds from the listwidget, they should be loaded to a buffer. My question is that I want that when I choose a sound and click on Add button the label that shows the name of the sound changes accordingly. So I wrote a slot function namely `addSound` whose code is:

```
bool MultipleSounds::addSound()
{
    connectBuffer();
    const QString& s = ui.listWidget->currentItem()->text(); // error here
    Ui_MultipleSoundsClass::label->setText(s);
    return true;
}
```

However, I get an error like:

> First-chance exception at 0x000000005E74976A (Qt5Widgetsd.dll) in
> Multiple        Sounds.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading
> location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x000000005E74976A
> (Qt5Widgetsd.dll) in Multiple Sounds.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
> reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

By the way, listwidget and label is defined in "ui_multiplesounds.h". How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you run your `addSound()` method step-by-step under debugger? What line causes the error?

Comment: The line starts with const qstring causes the error

Comment: Are you sure that `currentItem` exists in the moment you use it? Check it.

Comment: my listwidget has 2 items. Are you mentioning them or should I do something else?

Comment: I mean `currentItem` - not the items that just exists in your listwidget. I guess this should be a selected one. If you don't have a selected item, then your program will crash because you try to use `ui.listWidget->currentItem()` which is `nullptr` in such case. Check what `currentItem()` returns before trying to get its `text()`.

Comment: when I run the program I'm selecting an item from the list then clicking the button , but the same error still exist. Is it enough or should I do something more?

Comment: Yes, check what `currentItem()` do return when you call `addSound()`. Is it a null pointer?

Comment: I realized that the function is broken before entering currentItem() . It breaks after listwidget part. So, it doesn't return anything.